# Change background of iframe scr path page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this HTML code in my website:

```
<iframe id="dado" src="other/maindome.html" width="100%" height="840px" frameBorder="0">
  Your browser doesn't load this iframe.
</iframe>
```

When I use the function `apri()` I correctly change the iframe src path.

```
function apri(dat) {
document.getElementById('dado').src= dat;
}
```

The page `other/maindome.html` (for example) has a background called `bgframe2.png`, and this page is showed inside the iframe. How can I change the `maindome.html` background with `bgframe5.png`? I must change maindome's opacity too.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('backgroundImage', 'url_of_img.png');
        $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('opacity', 0.8);
    });"
</script>
```

I've googled aroud, I read some online stuff and I wrote the code above. By the way ,since I don't know jQuery, how could I call this function when I press a button (if it's correct)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First this line is not correct :

```
    $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('backgroundImage', 'url_of_img.png');
```

It should be :

```
    $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-image', 'url(url_of_img.png)');
```

**Answer to your comment :**

**HTML Button:**

```
 <input type='button' id='id_btn' />
```

**JS code :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#id_btn').click(function(){

    $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-image', 'url(url_of_img.png)');
    $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('opacity', 0.8);

 });
});
```

Comment: Add this in your answer if you can: who do I call that function by clicking a button? +1

Answer (score 1):

## [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KHqwL/)

#### HTML

```
<button id="btn">Hi</button>
<iframe id="dado" src="google.com" width="100%" height="840px" frameBorder="0">
   Your browser doesn't load this iframe.
</iframe>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
   $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-image', 'url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/)');
});
```